# Adding MathML String to DOM very fast best approach?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjax

What I do: I go through the DOM and translate e.g. Latex strings to MathML. This is very quick with Mathjax.

But we inject the generated MathML string

```
mathStr = jax.root.toMathML();
return jQuery(mathStr);
```

to the DOM and basically this last jQuery call makes everything slow for me.

Is there a way to get a tree instead of a string similar to toMathML() in a faster way?
Or is there a faster way to transform a MathML String to a tree?

Comment: Have you tried $("#something").html(mathStr) ?

Comment: This works for html. But MathML is not HTML :/ and not supported in this way.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(mathStr)` and show the value here?

Comment: Yes of course. It is a MathML string.